# Fail run Teaspoon CLI but success in browser

Tags: teaspoon

I have difficulties to run JS test suite CLI. Although tests pass in a web browser.

```
$ rake teaspoon
Starting the Teaspoon server...
Teaspoon running default suite at http://127.0.0.1:56362/teaspoon/default
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF

Failures:

  1)  global failure (1, 0, 1)
     Failure/Error: TypeError: instanceof called on an object with an invalid prototype property.

  2)  global failure (1, 0, 1)
     Failure/Error: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: App

  3)  global failure (1, 0, 1)
     Failure/Error: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: App

...
and so on
...

  19)  global failure (1, 0, 1)
     Failure/Error: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: App

Finished in 0.02100 seconds
19 examples, 19 failures

Failed examples:

teaspoon -s default --filter="undefined global failure"

...
and so on
...

teaspoon -s default --filter="undefined global failure"
rake teaspoon failed
```

Here is the [repo](https://github.com/mpugach/contact_list)

So why it sees `App` variable in browser and can't find it in CLI?

```
$ phantomjs -v
1.9.8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was about PhantomJS version. Use 2.0.0 now and tests are adequate in CLI.